# Take the index.php out of Code Igniter URLs

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I'm very new to Code Igniter (as in I just finished their "official" video tutorial), and I was wondering if there was a way to clean up the URLs just a little bit more.

Basically, is there some setting to keep the "index.php" out of the URL?

So instead of this...

> http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/blog/comments/

...you see this:

> http://localhost/codeigniter/blog/comments/

Or do I have to rewrite the URLs myself with .htaccess?

Comment: Don't use .htaccess. Use httpd.conf instead and turn off overrides. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an .htaccess is easier, other ways wouldn't probably work on shared hosting I guess.
That would do I guess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the following instructions.

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

As simple as 1 htaccess file and 1 modification to the config file

Answer (score 1):

You don't "have" to use the htaccess but doing it any other way would be a whole mass of kludge (Think redirecting in php from .../index.php/... to the non index.php version).

Any php dev worth their salt would do it in the .htaccess.